# Node.js - Only import function, not run entire file

Tags: node.js, typescript

I just noticed something and would like to understand why node behaves in this way.

I have 2 files like so:

`src/api/index-api.ts`
`src/worker/index-worker.ts`

They both have a simple `console.log('Started xxx')`

What I noticed was when I ran `node build/api/index-api.js` - I see both `Started API` and `Started Worker` in the console.

I figured out that in `src/api/index-api.ts` there is an `import` statement to use a function from `src/api/index-worker.ts`:

```
import { getContentFunction } from '../worker';
```

So I can see why they both get called.

But what exactly is the actual working of this - I mean what exactly happens and why is this so? As far as I was aware I'm just importing a specific function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `console.log` call is at the root of your `src/worker/index-worker.ts` file.

When you import a function, any declaration within the target file's global namespace is also ran since it may also instantiate variables per example. Importing a single function doesn't prevent that, it only means you want to keep a reference only to the specified function and not to all of them. It also allows you to import said function into your global namespace instead of having `worker.getContentFunction` per example.

TL;DR: your worker file still runs entirely, your import only decides on which references you keep.

---

Note about CommonJS: the `module.exports = {...}` statement at the end of the file sets what the file exports, which is ran like any other code in it. If an imported file didn't run entirely, such a statement would certainly be useless in itself. The interpreter has to know what's in the file so it can do whatever you asked it to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right. You want to call second file from first file. Try:

First file :

```
const {} = require("./second_file.js")
```

Second file :

```
console.log("Second file is working")
```

Comment: No - I just want to call a specific function from another file. Its calling the function file in my import - its just that it runs the entire file as well.